# Update table to make duplicate values unique

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with existing data that needs a primary key added to it. Before I can add the primary key, I need to check the existing column for duplicates and alter any so that when I alter the table all of my primary keys will be unique.

Example table:

| Name | id |
| --- | --- |
| John | 123456 |
| Steve | 123456 |
| Kelly | 122445 |
| Sam | 122567 |
| Chuck | 123456 |

Is it possible to have a query that can update the Steve and Chuck rows with a new unique id? I'm working with a larger amount of data so manually updating is not possible.

Comment: Create a [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) starting at `max(id) + 1`. Use the `nextval` from that sequence to replace duplicate IDs.

Comment: Oh cool. Great idea - I will give that a shot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the `name` field does not matter to you, then view this example:

Data before update:

| id | first_name |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | John |
| 123456 | Steve |
| 122445 | Kelly |
| 122567 | Sam |
| 123456 | Chuck |
| 123712 | Sarah |
| 123845 | Bryan |
| 123712 | Paul |

Update function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.update_table_ids()
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare 
    max_id integer; 
begin

    select max(id) into max_id from test.sample1;

    update test.sample1 up  
    set 
        id = tmp.new_id 
    from 
        (
            select 
                a1.*, 
                ((ROW_NUMBER () OVER ())::integer + max_id) as new_id 
            from test.sample1 a1 
            inner join 
                (
                    select min(id) as id, min(first_name) as first_name from test.sample1
                    group by id 
                    having count(*) > 1 
             
                ) a2 on a1.id = a2.id 
            where a1.first_name <> a2.first_name
        ) tmp 
    where up.id = tmp.id and up.first_name = tmp.first_name;

end;
$function$
;
```

After update:

| id | first_name |
| --- | --- |
| 122445 | Kelly |
| 122567 | Sam |
| 123456 | Chuck |
| 123845 | Bryan |
| 123712 | Paul |
| 123846 | John |
| 123847 | Steve |
| 123848 | Sarah |